# How to understand the density in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, neural-networks, density-estimation

We can calculate the conditional density using Eq.1[[3](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=gVRhIEajG1k)].
$$
p_{\theta, \Lambda}(y \mid \boldsymbol{x})=\frac{\exp \left(f_{\theta, \Lambda}(\boldsymbol{x})[y]\right)}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \exp \left(f_{\theta, \Lambda}(\boldsymbol{x})[k]\right)}\tag{1}
$$
where $f$ is the classifier.$f_{\theta, \Lambda}[k]$ represents the $k^{th}$ output of the last layer.

However, I cannot understand the sample space[[4](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ekkirkpat/SampleSpace.pdf)] of $x$ (an event in the sample space of $x$ is a pixel or an image?) a and $y$ (an event in the sample space of $y$ is outputting a certain logit vector or choosing $y$ as the prediction?).

Moreover, I don't know how to calculate $p(x,y)$. Assume that there are 6 images in the dataset and there are only 4 pixels ($x_0$, $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$) in each image. The images belong to 3 classes(i.e. the ground truth $y$ is 0, 1, and 2). Here is the dataset:

[image: dataset]

After the neural network to classify these images is trained, we can get the density of the dataset using Eq.1:

[image: the density of the dataset]

Then how can we calculate $p(x,y)$ using the above dataset and classifier(can we use $p(x,y)=p(y \mid x)p(x)$ to calculate $p(x,y)$?

What's more, what's the difference between density and probability in machine learning?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks very much.

Comment: $x$ is an image and $y$ is a label (class). The classifier is a model for the conditional probability $p(y|x)$. So if you know $p(x)$ you can calculate $p(y,x)$ as you mentioned. But what is your purpose ? usually in machine learning we don't have a model for $p(x)$

Comment: @J. Delaney Thank you for your comment. My purpose is to have a more in-depth study of the density in machine learning. I cannot understand the $p(x)$, too. Could you show an example of $p(x)$ using the dataset and classifier that I have posted in the question(by using a table or figure to describe it)?

Comment: Usually we don't know and don't need to know $p(x)$. In the context of images it is an extremely complicated object (a distribution over images) which is practically impossible to estimate.  Even for 4 pixel images you will need much more than 5 samples to be able to say something meaningful about it.

Comment: @J. Delaney Do we need to know $p(x,y)$? If we need to know it, how can we calculate it?